# Iterate over JSON data and insert into handlebars template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm trying to insert JSON data into my handlebars template. However, I'm having trouble getting the data out. Here is my js file:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import Handlebars from 'handlebars'
import indextmpl from '../templates/index.hbs!text'

let api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/movies' 

fetch(api_url).then(function(resp) {
  resp.json().then(function(movies) {
    console.log(movies)
    let tmpl = Handlebars.compile(indextmpl)
      for (let movie in movies) {
        let html = tmpl(movie)
          let title = $('#movie_title_main_page').innerHTML = movie.title
          $('#app').append(title)
      }
  })
})
```

and my template file:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="now_playing_section">
    <h1 id="now_playing_header">Now Playing</h1>
        <div id="movie_poster_wrapper">
          <p id="movie_title_main_page"></p>
          <p id="movie_poster"></p>
          <p id="movie_poster_release"></p>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using console.log(movies) to see if I can get the array back in the console and that is working as I see this:

[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Object5: Object6: Object7: Objectlength: 8__proto__: Array[0]

I'm using $('#app').append(title) to see if I can get the title out and append it to the #app div in my index.html file but it doesn't look it goes that far.

So not sure what i'm doing wrong but any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try this `let title = $('#movie_title_main_page').html(movie.title)`

Comment: Check out the Handlebars documentation - http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html - Look at **each**

Comment: Sorry, still getting nothing in my index.html file.

Comment: I'll look over the docs, thanks user2182349